# Have button width grow with text and align correctly

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a view with the following layout:

```
[Image] [button1] [label1] [button2]

        [label2]
```

button1 & button2 should grow and shrink based on how long the text will be, label1 will always contain the same text so it doesn't need to adjust just align with the buttons that will.

my iOS skills aren't very sharp (I'm more of an android dev) so I'm not sure how I achieve this.

Comment: I am not familiar with xamarin.ios but you should provide some code for people to better help you. What have you tried so far thats not working?

Comment: I'm just working on the storyboard so no code to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding these horizontal constraints:

1. Left Margin for image.
2. Fixed width constraint for image.
3. Right margin from the image to the button.
4. Right margin from button1 to label1. Then set that to 'more than or equal' like maybe 20pts. This means the spacing will always adjust itself to be as large as possible without going off screen (width autoresized to fit text).
5. Fixed width for label1.
6. Left margin from  button2 to label1.
7. Right margin from button2 to superview. Then set that to 'more than or equal' like maybe 20pts. This means the spacing will always adjust itself to be as large as possible without going off screen (width autoresized to fit text).

More on constraints :

[Apple developer autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html)

[Raywenderlich adaptive layout](https://www.raywenderlich.com/492-adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started)